# Changing the GET request query string value of the address bar from the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, url, query-string

Is this possible?

Say that we have something like this:

```
public ActionResult sim(string test)
{
        return View();
}
```

So i can call it by doing something like this:

`localhost:55319/test/rat/sim?test=hi`

Would it be possible to change the value of the test query string explicitly?

I tried it w/

```
@{
Request.Params.Set("test","hello");
}
```

and my program just breaks, what i want to happen is to change query string value of `test` without using another get request again and only from the view itself.

Comment: Query string is very generic way of passing values through http request, you can decide the query string when you create the link ! But i am not able to understand why you want to change that after the receiving the request ?

Comment: Simply for experimental purposes as of now, i just wanna know if it's possible to change it through code. I know it can be accessed through `Request` but would it be possible to change them as well?

Comment: are you trying to change it in browser url (in adress bar) ?

Comment: Long and short, the query string is part of the URL, i.e. part of the thing that uniquely identifies a resource. When you change it, you're changing the resource you're linking to, which to a browser means loading a new page. You can't change it server-side without performing a redirect. It's for this reason that `Request` is *read-only*, which is why you can't set a param to something else without getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

A) Server side: You can change a query string by redirecting to the same page with a different value for your parameter. The client will see a page refresh which may not be very pleasant.

```
return Redirect("/test/rat/sim?test="+ newValue);
```

B) Client side: If you just want the URL on the browser look different (without page refresh, i.e. redirect to a new page) you need to use javascript's History object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) which, very unfortunately, is not supported in old browsers.